# Making IF function more efficient

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the below format to get an output from a finite list of outputs based on a finite list of inputs but I was wondering if there was a faster/ more efficient way of executing the code? is there a way of shortening the code?

The code works as it is but I have always executed tasks like this and I was just curious to know if there was a better way from a self development point of view.

```
    If Intersect(Target, Range(Dev_Status & "6:" & Dev_Status & "1000")) = Dev_Raised_IN Then
    
        Target_Column = Dev_Raised
    
        ElseIf Intersect(Target, Range(Dev_Status & "6:" & Dev_Status & "1000")) = Dev_Draft_IN Then
        
            Target_Column = Dev_Draft
            
        ElseIf Intersect(Target, Range(Dev_Status & "6:" & Dev_Status & "1000")) = Dev_Review_IN Then
        
            Target_Column = Dev_Review
            
        ElseIf Intersect(Target, Range(Dev_Status & "6:" & Dev_Status & "1000")) = Dev_Comments_IN Then
        
            Target_Column = Dev_Comments
            
        ElseIf Intersect(Target, Range(Dev_Status & "6:" & Dev_Status & "1000")) = Dev_Approved_IN Then
        
            Target_Column = Dev_Approved
        
    End If
```

Comment: Well, an actual example with data may help understand your question, but I would be looking at a table and vlookup() or index() with match(), b ut until you show some real (well fake ie simulated) data that is just a suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

A good solution to *repetition* is often *abstraction*.

```
Dim src As Range
Set src = Me.Range(Dev_Status & "6:" & Dev_Status & "1000")
```

The `Intersect` function yields a `Range` object reference that is `Nothing` when the specified arguments don't intersect, and a `Range` representing the intersecting cells when they do. Assuming that code lives in some `Worksheet_Change` handler (and thus that `Me` is the `Worksheet` being handled) and `Target` is validated to only ever be a single cell, then we should be evaluating the intersection *once*:

```
Dim intersecting As Range
Set intersecting = Intersect(Target, Me.Range(Dev_Status & "6:" & Dev_Status & "1000"))
```

The code should handle that range being `Nothing`:

```
If intersecting Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

And then its value is safe to compare... or is it? If the cell contains a worksheet error value, its data type will be `Variant/Error`, and any kind of operation we do with that data type that doesn't involve `Variant/Error` operands on both sides of the operator, will throw a *type mismatch* error. So we should bail in that case too:

```
If IsError(intersecting.Value) Then Exit Sub
```

Now we can turn that repeated `If...ElseIf...End If` block into a `Select Case` block:

```
Select Case intersecting.Value

    Case Dev_Raised_IN
        Target_Column = Dev_Raised

    Case Dev_Draft_IN
        Target_Column = Dev_Draft

    Case Dev_Review_IN 
        Target_Column = Dev_Review

    Case Dev_Comments_IN 
        Target_Column = Dev_Comments

    Case Dev_Approved_IN 
        Target_Column = Dev_Approved

    Case Else
        'we don't have a target column:
        Target_Column = -1

End Select
```

The entire block can then be further streamlined into a simple one-liner key lookup, using either a keyed `Collection`, or a `Dictionary`.

Of course, such a collection needs to be initialized, but that can be made to happen *once* with a `Static` local, like so (first run enters the conditional, second run doesn't):

```
Static targetColumns As Collection
If targetColumns Is Nothing Then
    Set targetColumns = New Collection
    targetColumns.Add Dev_Raised, Dev_Raised_IN
    targetColumns.Add Dev_Draft, Dev_Draft_IN
    targetColumns.Add Dev_Review, Dev_Review_IN
    targetColumns.Add Dev_Comments, Dev_Comments_IN
    targetColumns.Add Dev_Approved, Dev_Approved_IN
End If

On Error Resume Next '"key not found"
Target_Column = targetColumns(intersecting.Value)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then Target_Column = -1
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Amazing! this is great, thank you for the in depth reply!